# Can I test model instance attributes in a controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller spec:

```
let!(:user) { create(:user, balance: 1000) }
let!(:group) { create(:group) }
let!(:parenthood) { create :parenthood, user: user }

before :each do
  sign_in user
end

context 'when user wants to pay for own children' do
  let(:box) { build(:box, user: user, person_amount: 10, group: group) }
  it "decreases user's balance" do
    post :create, box: box.attributes.merge({'box_memberships_attributes'=>{'0'=>{'id'=>'', 'student_id'=>parenthood.student.id, '_destroy'=>'0'}},
                                             'pay_own_children' => 'true'})
    expect(user.balance).to eq(990)
  end
end
```

Pay no attention to the ugliness of that test. :)

This test returns an error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(user.balance).to eq(990)

       expected: 990
            got: 1000.0 (#<BigDecimal:c973608,'0.1E4',9(27)>)

       (compared using ==)
```

However, if I debug the tested method in the controller with `binding.pry` everything is OK:

```
def create
  # some code
  binding.pry
  # current_user.balance.to_s return "990"
end
```

Does it mean I can not test states of models in controller specs?

Comment: Try reloading `user`: `expect(user.reload.balance).to eq(990)`

Comment: @MarekLipka: Add as answer! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reload your `user` instance:

```
expect(user.reload.balance).to eq(990)
```